# Angular material filtering table

Tags: angular, angular-material-5, tablefilter

i've tried the example, table with filter, in the angular material official page and i have a question: there is a way to add a space to concatenate object values? Because, as they said, "the row data reducing function will concatenate all the object values and convert them to lowercase".
I want to add more words, in the filter, not concatenate but with space.

For example:
[image]

If i add a space between the word, nothing will appears.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Can you show an example?

Comment: Yes, one second

Comment: Two things: 1) I'm surprised you get a result with `agenteagente`, as there is no column with that keyword, did you override the default filterPredicate? 2) why would `agente agente` return anything? What's the rationale behind it?

Comment: Because there is a data with name agent and surname agent

Comment: That's not how filters are supposed to work. I would stick to the default behaviour

Comment: I used the website's example